# Python script hangs out and saying Timeout thread invoked now

Tags: python, multithreading

I wanted to run various commands in parallel. and i am using threads for it.

Below is my program.

```
def run():
 DeviceList = { 
  'naa.500601': ['vmhba4:C0:T3:L0', 'vmhba4:C0:T2:L0', 'vmhba3:C0:T3:L0',
       'vmhba3:C0:T2:L0']
  'naa.50002': ['vmhba4:C0:T0:L2', 'vmhba3:C0:T0:L2']
  'naa.50002a':['vmhba4:C0:T0:L0', 'vmhba3:C0:T0:L0']
  'naa.6005': ['vmhba2:C0:T0:L1']
  'naa.60a98':['vmhba3:C0:T10:L11', 'vmhba4:C0:T12:L11', 'vmhba3:C0:T11:L11',    
     'vmhba4:C0:T13:L11', 'vmhba3:C0:T12:L11', 'vmhba3:C0:T13:L11', 
     'vmhba4:C0:T10:L11', 'vmhba4:C0:T11:L11']
   'naa.60a980': ['vmhba4:C0:T13:L43', 'vmhba3:C0:T12:L43', 'vmhba3:C0:T13:L43', 
      'vmhba4:C0:T10:L43', 'vmhba4:C0:T11:L43', 'vmhba3:C0:T10:L43',          
       'vmhba4:C0:T12:L43', 'vmhba3:C0:T11:L43']
 }
 Threads = []
 for device,paths in DeviceList.items():
  disablePathThread = threading.Thread(target = DisableStoragePath,args=(paths,))
  disablePathThread.start()
  Threads.append(disablePathThread)
 for t in Threads:
    t.join()

def DisableStoragePath(paths):
   for path in paths:   
      '''
       Execute some command
      ''' 
run() # Invoke Run method
```

When i run this program, it is running for some time and after that it is getting hung and after few minutes, thread is timing out with the error message 'Timeout thread invoked now for pathEnableDisable.py'

if i have more keys and values in my Dictionary 'DeviceList' it hangs
Could you please help me why the program is getting hung in between.

Comment: "Execute some command", what command?

Comment: What happens if you replace `threading.Thread` with `multiprocessing.Process` leaving the rest of the script the same?